# Xcode level locking system

Tags: xcode, locking, save, levels

im creating an iphone game. I have 21 levels and i want it so you must complete the level before in order to move on to the next level.  I have a different class for the home screen whcih includes the action buttons for the levels, and then the other class which controls each level. So basically i need help in for some way to save and then create an if then statement in the levels class allowing you to play the next level or not..

Example:

```
 if (*Help Here) {
[self level2];
//handle the method to display level 2
} else {
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Locked"
message:@"You must complete level one first"
delegate:nil
cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
otherButtonTitles:nil];
//message displaying they must beat lvl 1 first
}
```

Sorry, im very new to this and im only 14!

Edit: Found this out for myself, for people who need help

Save in nsuserdefaults and then check if the object is nil or not, worked for me

Comment: Describe in words when you will allow someone to go to a level...

Answer (score 0):

you can make it by saving the level number that just completed in someplace like NSUserDefault .. and check if the user clicking the number that level++ then it's ok.. if not .. give him alert